# Shared Pointer from Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Presently, am using a Shared Pointer from the Boost library.

```
class A
{
};
main
{
    boost::shared_ptr<class A> classpointer;
}
```

Under what cirumstances will the "classpointer" counter be incremented?

Comment: But you're not using shared pointer from boost library.

Comment: sorry Juanchopanza i should have used boost instead of std, now it has been edited properly. please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the pointer is empty, with a count of zero.

It will be incremented to one when you assign ownership of an object, for example

```
classpointer.reset(new A);  // owns the object, count=1
```

The count will be incremented if you copy this pointer, or any other pointer that shares ownership of the same object. It will be decremented if you destroy any such pointer, or reassign it to a different object, or reset it to be empty.

In general, the count for a particular object is equal to the number of shared pointers that currently share ownership of it. When the count becomes zero, so that no pointers remain sharing ownership, the object is automatically deleted.